# Thousands of mongo connections on EC2

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mongoose, pm2

My server is running on AWS EC2 and I noticed that it has 45000 mongo connections from our app's server IP. Though in code, there is only one mongo connection getting created at start.

Can anyone help me out here in debugging why it has so many connections?

PS: We use PM2 to restart the server, could it be because of that?

Comment: Can you reboot the server and check once if the connections are persist or not, check the stats of the server with any monitoring tool you are using ?

Comment: I did Netscape, and it showed my 45000 connections from same IP

Comment: Okay. Are you closing the connection properly or not, check once otherwise you'll leftover with making the newer once for every request. Also, check mongo by querying stats and then start debugging as like chaos monkey technique i.e. by stopping few thing in your entire stack... That might help in debugging...

Comment: Okay so I'm not closing the connection but it only creates when I start the app, never again. But when I close/exit/kill the app, shouldn't mongo connection close itself?

Comment: Few months back I went through the same problem. Then, I debugged all the applications which connects to mongo. Then, I figured out, there is python script running periodically wasn't using any framework so it keeps on creating new connection for every request. Ideally, it should close the connections, but, still you try in this way. Hopefully, you should get the solution.